# Circular Dependency between Form and Model

Tags: django, django-models

Here is a form:

```
class ToDoItemModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        from ToDoDashboard.models import ToDoItem
        model = ToDoItem

    fields = ['description', 'label', 'comment', ('start_date', 'due_date', 'time_estimate_hours')]

    def clean(self):
        start_date = self.cleaned_data.get('start_date')
        end_date = self.cleaned_data.get('due_date')
        if start_date > end_date:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Dates are incorrect")

        return self.cleaned_data
```

and here is a model:

```
class ToDoItem(models.Model):
    dashboard_column = models.ForeignKey(DashboardColumn, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField()
    label = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    due_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

    from ToDoDashboard.forms.ToDoItemForm import ToDoItemModelForm
    form = ToDoItemModelForm
```

Now it says *ImportError: cannot import name 'ToDoItem' from partially initialized module 'ToDoDashboard.models' (most likely due to a circular import)*

How to solve the problem?

Comment: why do you set form inside of model

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I incorrectly read your comment. I do that for custom validation in Admin, why not?

Comment: Then you set form in ModelAdmin not in your model, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form

Answer (score 0):

This is not a place to define form attribute  at all for your usecase, it should be defined inside ModelAdmin class as [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form)

```
PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): 
    exclude = ['age']
    form = PersonForm
```